# Phonegap- insert data in online and show it in offline using database

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

i want to insert data in database when the device is online ,if the device is offline  i want to show the data which is stored in database.

currently here i parse the data from rss feed and  insert the data in database when the device is online and i cannot show the same data when the device is become offline.And also i tried lot of times to show the data in offline,using the following code:

```
    document.addEventListener("offline", yourCallbackFunction, false);
 $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function (e, item) {

                       var titles=item.title;
                       var linked=item.link;

                    s += '<li><div class="itemTitle"><a href="' + item.link + '" target="' + def.TitleLinkTarget + '" >' + item.title + "</a></div>";
                    if (def.ShowPubDate) {
                        i = new Date(item.publishedDate);
                        s += '<div class="itemDate">' + i.toLocaleDateString() + "</div>";
                    }
                    if (def.ShowDesc) {
                        if (def.DescCharacterLimit > 0 && item.content.length > def.DescCharacterLimit) {
                            s += '<div class="itemContent">' + item.content.substr(0, def.DescCharacterLimit) + "...</div>";
                        }
                        else {
                            s += '<div class="itemContent">' + item.content + "</div>";
                       console.log(s);

                        }
                    }

                       // Wait for PhoneGap to load
                       //
                       document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

                       // Populate the database
                       //
                       function populateDB(tx) {

                       tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
                       tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (title, desc)');
                       tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (title, desc) Values(?,?)',[titles,s]);

                       }

                       // Query the database
                       //
                       function queryDB(tx) {

                       tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
                       }

                       // Query the success callback
                       //
                       function querySuccess(tx, results) {

                       var len = results.rows.length;
                       console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
                       for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
                       console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).title + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).desc);

    $("#apps ul").append('<li><a href="results.rows.item(i).desc"><span class="tab">' +results.rows.item(i).desc+'</span></a></li>');

                       }


                       }
                       document.addEventListener("offline", querySuccess, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

did you fire the event from the "ondeviceready" callback? i ask because this is a common mistake, but you need show us your code if you want anyone to be able to see whats wrong. 
anyway, you can alaways use the navigator.connection.type property, and if you feel like reinventing the wheel you can bind your callback function to an event fired when connection.type is none. for more details:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection
also:
did you check if the data actually stored on you local db?
try to see exactly where the problem is before asking for arbitrary help.

Comment: hi i update my sample code now.can you see it now and help me out am a new to phonegap

Answer (score 0):

as i thought, added the offline event listener before the device was ready, meaning before the functnionality needed to add event listener was loaded from your phonegap file. the correct way to write it is:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("offline", querySuccess, false);
}
```